# Define in C does not work when input is composite

Tags: c, definition

Problems using `define` in C. Works well when I call `OP(9)`, but when I call `OP(7+2)` I get 23. Why?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 #define OP(x) x*x;

 int main() {
 int x,y;

 x = 2;
 y = OP(7+2);
 printf("%d", y);

 return 0;

 }
```

Why prints 23 and not 81?

Comment: Use parentheses. This must be a duplicate question.

Comment: Parentheses — or lack thereof.  Look at `7 + 2*7 + 2` – that is `23`.  If you want `(7+2)*(7+2)`, add the parentheses: `#define OP(x) ((x)*(x))` — all of them!

Comment: "...but when I call `OP(7+2)`..." You cannot "call" `OP(7 + 2)`. `OP` is a macro, not a function. Macros cannot be "called". They can only be substutuded/replaced. The rest follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap `x` in parentheses in order to force precedence. However, it is also essential to wrap the entire expression in parentheses.

```
#define OP(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Comment: Better yet: `#define OP(x) ((x)*(x))`

Comment: going from -1 to +1 for the correction, reason can be seen by running these lines `#define ABS(a)  (a) < 0 ? -(a) : (a)` `printf("ABS(-3) - 1): %d\n", ABS(-3) - 1);`